# Git shows whole file text instead of that I commited

Tags: git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I've created rep and added some files.

After doing changes to my files, some are being displayed well - git is displaying lines of files which I modified, but for some files I see whole file text, and modified lines are totally different from what I changed.

Please check screenshot to see what happens:

[image]

Comment: That screen shot really doesn't explain anything.

Comment: What else do you expect ? This is what I see after I make change to one line.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the problem, the screenshot does not tell us much. If available in your enviroment, you may try running `git gui blame <file>` on the file to se what commits are in affect.

Answer (score 0):

I've found out the roots of problem.

You have to change line separator to LF instead of CR (this option can be found in phpstorm at the bottom in right side of editor).